# iOS push current view controller onto another view controller hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller (which is the root view of the main UINavigationController for my app) that is presenting another view controller hierarchy modally, by presenting a UINavigationController.  After the user interacts with the root view controller in the modal NavController, a detail VC is pushed onto the modal NavController's stack.  After some interaction with this detail VC, I'd like to push this detail VC back onto the original hierarchy, and dismiss the modal NavController/it's root view controller, all without the user seeing the change in this hierarchy.  Right now I have something like this:

In MyViewController1 (root of the main NavController hierarchy):

```
UINavigationController *newModalNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:someRootViewController];
[self presentViewController:newModalNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then in the someRootViewController above, after some interaction (e.g. a button click), I push the detail view controller onto the modal hierarchy:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Finally, in the detailVC, after some more interaction:

```
UINavigationController *mainNavController = /* Get main nav controller here (i.e. non-modal one) */

// Dismisses the modal view hierarchy (detailVC gets -(void)viewDidDisappear)
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

// Repush the detailVC back onto the main hierarchy (detailVC gets -(void)viewDidAppear)
[mainNavController pushViewController:self animated:NO];

// Keyboard was on screen before interaction; make it stay on screen after pushing
// detailVC onto main nav hierarchy
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

This all works (clicking back on the detailVC's navigationItem after pushing it onto the mainNavController's hierarchy goes back to the original rootViewController, MyViewController1), except when the keyboard is on screen in the detail view controller as it is being switched, it gets hidden and then animates back up, instead of just staying on screen (because the view is disappearing for a second as the presentingViewController dismisses the modal nav controller, whose hierarchy the detailVC is a part of, and then reappears as it gets pushed onto the mainNavController's stack, and the textView grabs first responder again).

Is there a better way to change which navigation hierarchy the detail view controller is a part of, possibly one that doesn't involve the view disappearing, and thus the keyboard being hidden and immediately reshown?

Comment: I'd say initially that you shouldn't be abusing the hierarchy like this and that the affect will be confused users (you destroy the sense of flow through the transitions). Why not make the transition after the keyboard is dismissed?

Comment: Consider for example iMessage; when composing a new message, after clicking send, the message view controller transitions from being a modal view controller to being part of the view controller hierarchy.  The keyboard remains showing on the screen, and the text field remains first responder.  I want to do something similar to that.

Comment: @ewald : Did you figure it out? If so, can you share your results?

Comment: @BrainOverfl0w I never figured out a good way to do this - had a hack that worked in iOS 6 but doesn't work well in 7.  I don't think it's an interaction Apple wants to allow; as Wain points out, in most situations it's probably confusing to the user.  Let me know if you figure it out.